# Unable to attach Threejs EventDispatcher to custom objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

This seems really straightforward but I'm a bit new to JavaScript and struggling. The docs give this example:

```
// Adding events to a custom object

var Car = function () {

    this.start = function () {

        this.dispatchEvent( { type: 'start', message: 'vroom vroom!' } );
    };
};

// Mixin the EventDispatcher.prototype with the custom object prototype
Object.assign( Car.prototype, EventDispatcher.prototype );

// Using events with the custom object
var car = new Car();

car.addEventListener( 'start', function ( event ) {

    alert( event.message );
});

car.start();
```

In the header of my main page I include [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.js), which implements EventDispatcher. In the body I load in my app.js, which is where I stick the example code. At this point it throws `EventDispatcher is not defined`. If I pull in [EventDispatcher.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js/blob/master/src/EventDispatcher.js) separately before this, it all works.

I guess this is a simple loading / execution order thing, and I'd like to know how to resolve this without needing the extra EventDispatcher.js bit. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var Car = function () {

    this.start = function () {

        this.dispatchEvent( { type: 'start', message: 'vroom vroom!' } );
    };
};

Object.assign( Car.prototype, THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );

var car = new Car();

car.addEventListener( 'start', function ( event ) {

    alert( event.message );

});

car.start();
```

three.js r.85